# Css overflow with embeded div and absolute postition?

Tags: css

I tried to do this:
http://jsfiddle.net/kritya/wTnEg/

When i click on the div with id `add` but when it exceeds the class with `content-doing` it doesnt gets scrollers.

What have i been doing wrong ?

Comment: in what browser. It works in Chrome

Comment: Also reproducible in FF6 on Windows. Making the box taller did fix it for me, but the scrollbar does look awkward.

Comment: yea. But when i change it to something like this. http://jsfiddle.net/kritya/wTnEg/4/ I want it on the x axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting scroll bars in FF on a mac. The height of the block at 1.5em might just be too narrow to have the scroll bar be of any use. Try making that container a little taller right out of the gate.

Comment: Hmm. But how do i get this going http://jsfiddle.net/kritya/wTnEg/4/
I want it on the x.

Comment: @kritya a width in `%` does not give a x scroller. change it for a `px`

Comment: Also, `overflow:auto` tends to generally give you a Y scroll bar. Maybe adding an `white-space:nowrap` as well would work?